# Can not run JavaScript config in ui-view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a demo use `Angular UI Router`: [Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/XXl8g2x3pe3aP7QXdLJv?p=preview)

**app.js:**

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.router'])
.config(function( $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
    .state('main', {
        url: '',
        template: '<div ui-view></div>',
    })
    .state('main.home', {
        url: '/home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html',
    controller: 'HomeCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'home'
  });
})
.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  console.log('home');
}]);
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <title>UI Router</title>

  </head>

  <body ng-app="app">
    <a ui-sref=".main.home" href="javasacript:void(0)">Show Agoda</a>
    <div ui-view=""></div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.1/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

**home.html**

```
<div>
  Home Page
</div>

// This is code I need to work
<script type="text/javascript">
  agoda_ad_client = "1650121_5092";
  agoda_ad_width = 200;
  agoda_ad_height = 200;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//banner.agoda.com/js/show_ads.js"></script>
```

I would like when click to `Show Agoda` link, it will go to home page and show `Angoda Banner`. But it not working.

It works fine when I use without `ui-view`:

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <title>UI Router</title>

  </head>

  <body ng-app="app">
    <a ui-sref=".main.home" href="javasacript:void(0)">Show Agoda</a>
    <div ui-view=""></div>
    // This code work fine
    <script type="text/javascript">
      agoda_ad_client = "1650121_5092";
      agoda_ad_width = 200;
      agoda_ad_height = 200;
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//banner.agoda.com/js/show_ads.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.1/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

How can I use `Agoda code` within `ui-view` (`home.html`). Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try your code with following a link:
`<a ui-sref=".main.home" href="javasacript:void(0)">Show Agoda</a>` replace this with `<a ui-sref="main.home" href="javasacript:void(0)">Show Agoda</a>`

Also replace `<div ui-view=""></div>` with `<div ui-view></div>`

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks, This is not solution for my question :)